# Odoo 14: How can I share the same bank account in child companies?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I created a multicompany structure in Odoo 14 because I need to know the different earnings and loss of each line of my business and generate different invoice templates from each line.

**0-Main**
1 - develop line
2 - content line
3 - marketing line

I wish to share the same bank account for child lines, and do bank reconciliation at the same time. How can achieve this? By default, I can't do it because Odoo need a bank account for each company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is create analytics accounts to track each line, not multicompany structure. The invoice personalization for each kind of client could be done using modules.